# How to find users' Internet Explorer history on Terminal Server (Windows 2008 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, internet-explorer, windows-terminal-services

So I need to see histories for dozens of agents on TS. Where IE stores that, and is there any easier way then going manually to each users folder? Thanks.

Comment: IE history is one of those things that changes location with practically every version of Windows AND every version of IE. You'll most likely find it in a *.dat file *somewhere* in the user's profile, that needs a special application to be able to read it.  http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_History_File_Format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE histories are stored here :

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
```

Actually, as far as i know, there is not an easier way than going to each users folder. But this could be easily automated using `powershell`.

Comment: I can't find nothing that looks like history. Can you be more specific please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked "show hidden files and folders" AND unchecked "hide files protected by the system OS" ? (sorry i am french my os is french, i don't know the real traduction for it)